# Maven Ant deploy - OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: maven, ant, out-of-memory, heap-memory, pom.xml

## Scenario

While using the *Maven Ant Task* `artifact:deploy`, I'm encountering the error `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

I'm only getting the error if the size of the file being deployed is greater than 25 MB. My artifacts are not greater than 50 MB in size.

> What could the reason be? And, what can I do to fix it?

---

### Code snippet

```
        <artifact:deploy file="@{app.name}.jar">
            <pom file="@{pom.file}"/>               

            <remoteRepository url="http://xxx.com:xxx/xxx-webapp/content/repositories/xxx-releases/">
                <authentication username="xxx" password="xxx" />
            </remoteRepository>
        </artifact:deploy>
```

---

### Existing solutions

Most online results indicate that it's something to do with the **JVM default heap size** and that it can be fixed by setting the appropriate **environmental variables**.

However, I would want the Ant scripts to run on any computer and **not to depend** on the environmental variables.

> Is there a way to configure these settings in the Ant scripts or the
>   `POM` file?

#### EDIT

The `install-provider` task (http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/install-deploy.html) seems to work for some people. I keep getting download errors when I use it.

---

### Answer

It turns out that I'm **not getting** the Java heap error when I run my Maven Ant task on a different machine (which probably has more memory allocated to the JVM heap). Hence, I haven't attempted the solution mentioned by @Attila, though it seems to be going in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once ant is running, you cannot change the heap size of the JVM runing ant.  So your only option is to run the task that comsumes a large amount of memory in a separate JVM, specifying enough heap space.  Note this relies on the task allowing you to *fork* a new JVM to execute the task

*Update*: I could not find a way to specify to fork the maven (deploy) task, but [this page](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html) specifies how you can define a macro to run maven using the *java* task (note that this relies on maven beeing installed and properly configured on the machine) (see the "Using the Java Task" section)

Comment: would an artifact not more than 50 MB in size require that option? I'm assuming there's probably a simpler way of dealing with it...

Comment: Depending on what is involved, building can sometimes take a surprising amount of memory -- unfortunately I'm not familiar with the maven task, so don't know if there is an easier way

Answer (score 1):

please try to increase VM memory, eg.: -Xmx512m
if you are using ANT, you can add it to the ANT_OPTS environment variable: ANT_OPTS="-Xmx512m"

Comment: I want something that doesn't require me to depend on changing the environmental variables. My script should be able to run on any machine without having to change the machine environmental configurations.

Comment: You can try add it to bat file, eg.:

        ANT_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
        CALL ant -q -f ...

Comment: The problem with a batch file is that it would environment specific and also not the cleanest of approaches. I'm wondering if anything can be added to the Ant scripts or the POM file.

Comment: So, you need to change VM memory at run time, but it is impossible :) sorry.